# Google as consumer in OpenID context?

Tags: openid, single-sign-on, consumer

It is a quite interessting concept realizing Single Sign on with OpenID.

I am using an OpenID Provider like (my.xlogon.net), and have registered few webpages with it and it works like a charme.

But I am not able to register per example my Google Account with my openID Provider.

Does Google don't want to play the consumer role ? Or what is the Reason.

Answer (score 0):

Google is no longer supporting OpenID 2.0 and is moving everyone to OpenID Connect. Please see their website -

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for the information. Ok, Google ends the support of it. But anyhow ever exists the possibility that that Goolge is the customer and I can use another OpenID provider to automatically login into google ?

Comment: They might've supported YahooID and someone else (??) as official OpenID providers but AFAIK they have never supported ad-hoc OpenID Providers. They want to own your identity so you'll always start with Google and not somewhere else (unless you are a business and using SAML 2.0 to login to GApps).